# Как работает push уведомления в androide и iphone

Tags: android, ios

Мне интересна сама технология пуша от гугла, ведь телефон должен как то отправлять запрос гуглу передавая свой адрес и порт и ждать ответа от сервера о каких либо  событиях(лонгполлинг).
И получается что андроид и айос целый день отправляет запрос и ждет ответа от серверов(гугла, эпла) и соответственно это на это уходит колосальное количество энергии в день(относительно).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, никакой магии нет. Пуши получаются с сервера через постоянное соединение с ним по сокетам. Не знаю как конкретно на иОС реализовано, но в случае Android соединение держит приложение `GooglePlayServices` - оно имеет особые привилегии в системе и не прибивается оной как обычные приложения в случае нехватки памяти, ухода в сберегающий режим etc. И да, оно постоянно потребляет ресурсы.

Comment: А на низком уровне это в итоге обычный сокет который и ждет ответа и так все время. Получается это колосальное количество энергии за целый день уходит.

Comment: интересно, это что получается гугл держит одновременно почти миллиард сокетов  ради пушей?

Comment: @AlexanderBelov, ну, какие-то оптимизации там, наверное, есть. А так да - если хочется радикально повысить живучесть телефона надо сносить все гугловые приложения. Но после этого большинство приложений либо будут нестабильны или вообще не запустятся. Гугл, думаю, может себе позволить столько держать. Так они монополизируют рынок пушей. Раньше вот был `parse.com`, но они его выжали с рынка.

Comment: Понял, спасибо и еще интересно тогда, что за рынок пушей, разве от гугла все это не бесплатно насколько я знаю, для разработчиков. В чем для гугла кроме конечно поддержки своей платформы, выгода.

Comment: @AlexanderBelov, введя свои бесплатные пуши он разорил другие сервисы, их предоставлявшие. Теперь, например, если вы захотите выкладывать приложение не только в PlayMarket вам придётся как-то с пушами выкручиваться, т.к. на телефонах с другими магазинами приложений может не быть сервисов гугла и пуши не будут работать. Если бы вы использовали стороннее решение, то оно работало бы на любом девайсе, независимо от гугла. И так во всём. Я бы, например, выложил свои приложения в другие сторы, но там столько на гугл завязано, что я просто не готов тратить на это время. В итоге - монополия.

Comment: Как я понимаю делать запрос нужно только для того чтобы сообщить порт и ip адрес телефона, а нельзя и сделать так, допустим гугл забронировал порт для себя в телефоне 3425 и никто его не возьмет, а вот айпи адрес сообщать только тогда когда меняется айпи адрес или появляется сеть. так запросов намного меньше станет

Comment: @AlexanderBelov, насколько мне известно у девайса нет уникального IP - он всегда в какой-то сети и ему IP может роутер внутрисетевой дать а на реальном IP в итоге может не один девайс сидеть. Засим единственная возможность - постоянное поддержание прямого соединения с сервером - иначе пуш некуда отправлять.

Comment: ЮрийСПб А как насчет web socket, нельзя ли их использовать?

Comment: @AlexanderBelov, это ничего не изменит, правила останутся теми же. Нужно постоянное соединение.